# Matlab hypergeom returns symbolic results after I install Python

Tags: python, matlab, symbolic-math

I recently found a problem when I use **MATLAB**. I have used the function "**hypergeom**" for years and it works well until today I found that it always returns symbolic results, even if all the parameters are numbers. For example, if I type

hypergeom([1, 2], 2.5, 2)

in the command window, then it appears:

ans =

```
                    -1.217418930 - 0.8330405509  i
```

and the workspace shows that

ans <1*1 sym>

(sorry I cannot post images due to the low reputation.)

---

I guess the problem may be caused by Python, since I recently tried to learn Python and used scipy.special.hyp2f1. I don't know if it will affect the Matlab.

Anyone could help me to let the  **hypergeom** function return back to normal? I mean when the inputs are numbers, then it returns floating-point. Thank you!

Comment: What does `which hypergeom` return?

Comment: Also, does `sym/hypergeom([1, 2], 2.5, 2)` return the same as `hypergeom([1, 2], 2.5, 2)`?

Comment: @LuisMendo, let me have a check now.

Comment: which hypergeom returns : D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\maple\hypergeom.m

Comment: sym/hypergeom([1, 2], 2.5, 2) returns:  Error using sym/mrdivide (line 9)
Error using maplemex
Error, invalid input: MTM:-mrdivide uses a 2nd argument, B, which is missing

Comment: @LuisMendo, so was it caused by Maple? I did installed Maple long times ago, and "hypergeom" doesn't go wrong like this before.

Comment: Old Matlab versions did use Maple as symbolic engine, but I think that the path `\toolbox\maple\hypergeom.m` is not normal. Maybe when you installed Maple it recognised that Matlab was already installed and added that function to your Matlab installation? Also, do you have Matlab Symbolic Toolbox? (type `ver`).

Comment: I've added the  symbolic-math tag to your question so that you can get more help

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: There have been a few other questions in the past where Maple installs (or possibly some other program that installs some part of Maple) have screwed up some of the symbolic math in Matlab. It's very confusing to debug and I'm not sure you'll find satisfying answers. Definitely make sure `symengine` returns something like "MuPAD symbolic engine". Try restarting Matlab. You may need to re-install Matlab if you can't find the problem.

Comment: You can of course try removing the `D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\maple` toolbox. Both versions of Matlab's `hypergeom` should be located within `D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic` (there really only one version, by the way, both call the same underlying C function within the MuPAD engine).

Comment: Thank you all! (Seems I cannot at all of you.) The version I am using is "MATLAB Version: 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)". I do find "hypergeom.m" within the folder D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic. Is there any way I do not need to re-install Matlab? @horchler, how can I removing \toolbox\maple toolbox? Directly delete the maple folder?

Comment: @LuisMendo, thanks. I typed ver and there is a long list. But I do not find "Symbolic Toolbox". However, I can find the folder: D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic in my computer.